# Event Study Test Statistic Formula Source Problem

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, t-test

As part of my thesis, I'm currently doing an event study. In one class, we got the formulas below for the t-statistic which I've used in my paper. Stupidly, I've trusted the reference to MacKinlay (1997) in the documents (actually from my co-supervisor). While proofreading and checking references, I just realized that the formula presented is not in MacKinlay and while I can find it on the internet, I cannot find a source (which I obviously need). Does anyone know where this formula is from or can you find a source?

Formulas:

$$\bullet~~~~ \frac{\textrm{AAR}_t}{\sigma}\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$$

$$1.~~~~s_t^2= \frac1{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^N (\textrm{AR}_{i,t}-\textrm{AAR}_t)^2,~~~~\frac{\textrm{AAR_t}}{s_t}\sqrt N\sim t_{N-1}.$$

Highly appreciate any help, as this would require me to change everything and use a different test statistic!

Answer (score 0):

Found it, this formula is from Brown and Warner (1985) in the Appendix

Comment: Could you add the relevant section here in your post from the said literature?